# MapControllerRoute , value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I started a web-api  project on my macbook (windows mode) and everything works fine. But when i download same project from Github to my windows PC i got this when i start my program.

This is my Maccontroller,

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

And this is my Error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'
```

I have been googling this for 2 days now and reinstalled my packages, still got the same problem. I dont see anyone have this issue

I just dont understand why it doesnt work on my PC its also windows...

I have a Web-api project and a Web-app project in same solution but they are not combined yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Reinstalled all the packages, so i think that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into the same error. I discovered that if you are using the `RazorRuntimeCompilation` package, it causes this error. If you remove it from your packages, it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).